# ¿Por qué este programa se ejecuta cada 1 segundo en bucle?

Tags: javascript

Tenía que crear un reloj que emitiese la hora en la consola cada 1 segundo y la cosa es que lo he conseguido pero esperaba que fuese necesario usar el setInterval, alguien me lo puede explicar por qué se repite el código cada 1 segundo? Gracias.

Código:

```js
let clock = () => {
  const practiceNow = new Date();
  const practiceNowHours = practiceNow.getHours();
  const practiceNowMinutes = practiceNow.getMinutes();
  const practiceNowSeconds = practiceNow.getSeconds();

  let time = `${practiceNowHours}:${practiceNowMinutes}:${practiceNowSeconds}`
  setTimeout(clock, 1000);
  console.log(time);
}

clock();
```

Comment: ¿Has [investigado algo](https://es.javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)? ¿Cuál es tu probema en concreto? ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Tu función es recursiva y antes de finalizar siempre ejecuta un nuevo `setTimeout` que la vuelve a invocar recursivamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se ejecuta cada 1 segundo porque tu se lo estas diciendo aquí:

```javascript
setTimeout(clock, 1000);
```

Concretamente esta llamada a la función `setTimeout` está interpretando esta sintaxis [(visto en su documentación)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setTimeout):

> setTimeout(funcion[, retraso]);

Y si te fijas bien, **antes** de enviar el mensaje a la consola, le estas diciendo que **ejecute otra vez** la función `clock` (sin aún haber terminado la ejecución actual aún).

En ese momento se estan ejecutando **dos** funciones `clock` a la vez, donde *una **terminará** escribiendo en consola el tiempo calculado* mediante `console.log(time)`, y la otra *se ejecutará desde el principio*, llegando otra vez al `setTimeout` y repitiendo de nuevo el mismo comportamiento, y asi indefinidamente.

Lo curioso del tema es que acabo de buscar, gracias al aporte de @FranAcuna en los comentarios de la pregunta, si ésta función `clock` es **recursiva**, y me he encontrado esto ([fuente](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/como-entender-recursividad-en-javascript/)):

> Si no le dices a la función cuándo detenerse, entonces sucederá algo
> llamado **stackoverflow**(!!!). La pila(stack) se va a llenar con funciones que
> se están llamando, pero que no regresan ni se quitan de la pila.

Bueno, ahora al menos ya intuyo qué significa este sitio :-)